# Why isn't my program displaying the integer I'm outputting?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<string>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    int i;  
    cout<<"enter ur no. plz";  
    cin>>i;  
    cout<<"ur no. is:"<<i;  
    cin.get();  
    return 0;   
}
```

This code is not displaying the integer I entered. It returns back after entering an integer and hitting enter. I am using dev C++.

Comment: Are you saying that it is only returning the integer after you press enter?

Comment: Try to put an `<< endl` behind i in the `cout`, maybe it is a buffering issue.

Comment: He's saying that his MS-Windows command prompt window (which was created by his IDE) is exiting (and disappearing) immediately.

Comment: Do you mean that the console window disappears to quickly?

Comment: @Rob: Didn't dev-c++ have an extra option to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @rob -- yeah u got me right, same thing is happening, when i enter the integer and hit enter (so that that integer will display on the screen), then the screen just exit immediately. How to tackle this. i have put it endl. it is not effective.

Comment: Test any of the three solutions suggested by @Benjamin Lindley. If one of them works for you, accept his answer.

Comment: @Nobody - I know that MSVC does, but a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=dev+c%2B%2B+window+closes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) implies that DevC++ doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the user enters the integer, there is still a newline character left in the input buffer.  cin.get() reads that character, then the program immediately ends.  You could put an additional call to get if you want the program to stay open.  Or, before the call to get, you could have a call to ignore:

```
std::cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

That would clear the newline character from the buffer.

Or you could run your program from the command line, you'll see the output then.

Comment: std::cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
adding this line solves my problem. thanks benjamin.
but plz tell me why is it so difficult to run just the simple program on IDE devc++.

Answer (score 4):

Add some `endl`s:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<string>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    int i;  
    cout<<"enter ur no. plz"<<endl;  
    cin>>i;  
    cout<<"ur no. is:"<<i<<endl;  
    cin.get();  
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Or just `flush` if no newline is wanted.